# Object.fromEntries is not a function

Tags: tailwind-css

I've been following Tailwind's tutorials and when. I get to the part of the tutorial where they ask me to run

-npx tailwindcss init,
-Object.fromEntries is not a function

I get the following error. How do I solve this?

I'm trying to learn tailwind css and I got a problem that I don't understand, please help me guys

Comment: Seems you are using a quite old version of nodejs. `Object.fromEntries` is supported since v12. Check your node version with `node -v`

Answer (score 1):

first run `node -v` in your terminal to check you have nodejs or not
then run `npm init -y` to install dependencies'
then run `npm install -D tailwindcss`
after that run `npx tailwindcss init`
hopefully after doing this you will be able to process further into your project